# Is there a plugin that could replace Filezilla for vim?

Tags: vim, ftp, remote

I'm sick and tired of changing windows all the time just to upload a file. I would like a way to do that fast right from `vim`. Is there such a thing? I download the files, I edit them and then I want to upload them, all manually, but I don't want to type huge commands to do it each time.

Linux user that likes to do as much as possible from the terminal. That is... everything!

Answer (score 1):

I've made one

https://github.com/carlos-cabgj/autodeploy.vim

But It will send your data only when you save using python or pscp and plink

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is hope, and you don't even need to download the files, see [netrw](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075):

`REMOTE EDITING
    :e dav://machine[:port]/path                  uses cadaver
    :e fetch://[user@]machine/path                uses fetch
    :e ftp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path        uses ftp   autodetects <.netrc>
    :e http://[user@]machine/path                 uses http  uses wget
    :e rcp://[user@]machine/path                  uses rcp
    :e rsync://[user@]machine[:port]/path         uses rsync
    :e scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path        uses scp
    :e sftp://[user@]machine/path                 uses sftp

REMOTE READING
    :Nread ?                                      give help
    :Nread "machine:path"                         uses rcp
    :Nread "machine path"                         uses ftp   with <.netrc>
    :Nread "machine id password path"             uses ftp
    :Nread "dav://machine[:port]/path"            uses cadaver
    :Nread "fetch://[user@]machine/path"          uses fetch
    :Nread "ftp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path"  uses ftp   autodetects <.netrc>
    :Nread "http://[user@]machine/path"           uses http  uses wget
    :Nread "rcp://[user@]machine/path"            uses rcp
    :Nread "rsync://[user@]machine[:port]/path"   uses rsync
    :Nread "scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path"  uses scp
    :Nread "sftp://[user@]machine/path"           uses sftp

REMOTE WRITING
    :Nwrite ?                                     give help
    :Nwrite "machine:path"                        uses rcp
    :Nwrite "machine path"                        uses ftp   with <.netrc>
    :Nwrite "machine id password path"            uses ftp
    :Nwrite "dav://machine[:port]/path"           uses cadaver
    :Nwrite "ftp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path" uses ftp   autodetects <.netrc>
    :Nwrite "rcp://[user@]machine/path"           uses rcp
    :Nwrite "rsync://[user@]machine[:port]/path"  uses rsync
    :Nwrite "scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path" uses scp
    :Nwrite "sftp://[user@]machine/path"          uses sftp`

Comment: That's the thing, I want to download the files.Being able to fetch entire dirs, and edit them, and upload them e.t.c e.t.c. I want the stuff that filezila can do but from within vim.

Comment: If I wanted to maintain a local copy of the files, I'd be storing the files in `git` and using the `fugitive` plugin to commit changes upstream.

Comment: I like that idea, but I'm not the admin of the server, I can't install git on it. And even if I was, I would have no clue how to set it up. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any plugin that works exactly like what you describe. The only FTP plugins I have used is netrw and there's also [FTPSync](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=934) but both seem to be quite far from what you have in mind.

You didn't specify what OS you are using: are you on Windows or Linux? There are a number of very good FTP clients on Mac OS X (like the great Yummy FTP and totally worth the price) with "folder-watchers" that would provide exactly what you want except outside of Vim.

If you are on Linux, [this recent thread on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1i6l39/is_there_an_application_on_linux_or_script_that/) may be interesting. Mounting your FTP server is another option.